# Does adding new nodes to a graph change the indices of the old nodes?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a `networkx` graph object `G`. Each node has an index with respect to `G.nodes()`. I keep track of the nodes indices because I do some computations with the adjacency matrix, because each row index in the adjecency matrix corresponds to the node index in `G.nodes()`. But now I want to add new nodes to the graph, would that change the indices of the old nodes?

I'm not removing any nodes.

```
G = nx.Graph()

#add some nodes to G.

#record the indices of those nodes in a dictionary that maps from a node name to a node index from the list G.nodes()

#add more nodes and edges to G.

#Did the indices of the old nodes change?
```

Comment: Could you post more code so we can see more clearly what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

NetworkX stores graph nodes in the attribute `node` of the class `Graph`. Since `node` is a dictionary, the order is not guaranteed and may change.

If you could give some more details about what you're trying to achieve, we could help you more. You could try keeping a dictionary mapping from nodes to names, or if all you need is the node names, you could also assign names to nodes directly:

```
G.add_node('John')
G.add_node('Jane')
```

You can also use node attributes, such as

```
G.add_node(0, name='John', age=24)
G.add_node(1, name='Jane', age=27)
```

and then read them as

```
G.node[0]
>>> {'name': 'John', 'age': 24}
```

You can also use arbitrary objects as graph nodes.